# Converting hydrogen to methane

Tags: reaction-mechanism, hydrocarbons, hydrogen

I am in need of small amount of pure methane for laboratory purpose.

I have hydrogen generator in the lab.

Is there a possibility of generating methane from hydrogen ?

May be make hydrogen flow over heated graphite ? ( I am newbie and just trying to get the idea...)

Any help in this direction is helpful. thanks.

Comment: In laboratory, methane is made by heating sodium acetate with soda-lime.

Comment: I'd just buy a lecture bottle of methane of the required purity -  the impurities would be known and upper bounds given by the vendor.